# Why are my here-docs (<<-) giving me a syntax error?

Tags: bash, operators

```
methods() {
        cat <<-!
        start
        stop
        restart
        reload
        status
        methods
        !
}
```

Is this correct I am getting error

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: To the close voter: really? You think `bash` isn't _programming?_ You do see that there's a function being defined in that question up there, don't you?

Answer (score 6):

For here-docs in ancient shells, you have to match the tag *exactly.* That means:

```
methods() {
        cat <<!
        start
        stop
        restart
        reload
        status
        methods
!
}
```

Yes, at the start of the line, although you could do tricky things like `cat <<'^I!'` to set the marker to a single tab followed by `!`.

Now `bash` (and possibly earlier shells) fixed that with the `<<-` variant which strips off all leading tabs from your data lines and the end marker before processing. That way, you could still indent nicely:

```
methods() {
        cat <<-!
        start
        stop
        restart
        reload
        status
        methods
        !
}
```

But, note the proviso: it strips *tabs,* not whitespace in general. If you have spaces (or *any* non-tab character, printable or otherwise) anywhere before that `!` character, it won't work.

If you're using `vi`, you can enter `:set list` to see the non-printable characters a bit better, otherwise `xd` or `od -xcb` can give you a hex dump of your file.

Comment: Early shells means 'really ancient'.  7th Edition Unix (1979) did not support it, but I believe that System III (and I'm practically certain that System V) supported the 'here doc with dash' notation.

Comment: Thank you, @Jonathan, for pointing out my advancing years :-)

Comment: From one antique to another (probably rather less) antique - no problem.  The sad part is I started on a 7th Edition Unix with some System III enhancements (and bits from PWB).